# MySQL database join

Tags: mysql

I currently have two database tables:

```
DB1                      
+-----------------------------+
| termid | term               |
+-----------------------------+
| 1      | Piccadilly line    |
| 2      | Circle line        |
+-----------------------------+
```

and

```
DB2                     
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| factid | termid  | facttype      | fact               | 
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 1      | 1       | station       | Holborn            | 
| 2      | 1       | station       | Green Park         | 
| 3      | 1       | opened        | 1906               | 
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I use the following code to query the tables:

```
SELECT db1.term as `term`,  
      GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(db2.facttype, ': ', db2.fact)) as facts 
FROM db1 
LEFT JOIN db2 
   ON db1.`termid` = db2.termid 
WHERE db1.`term` = 'Piccadilly line' 
GROUP BY db1.term
```

Which returns the results:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| term | facts                                                | 
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1    | station: Holborn, station: Green Park, opened: 1906  | 
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How do I need to change the SELECT query so that the following is displayed:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| term | facts                                                | 
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1    | station: Holborn and Green Park, opened: 1906        | 
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what is `<br/>` ?? Is it typo ?

Comment: Why are they prefixed 'db', and why are they suffixed with an integer ?

Comment: The tables are just named db1 and db2 for simplicity, and, yes "<br/>" was a mistake. @Strawberry

Comment: I see. That's simpler than calling them, say, `terms` and `facts` !?!?

Comment: @user3287037 Yes it can be done Do you know how to write functions in MySQL?

Comment: @user3287037 can you add "create table" or "show create table" for both table here?

Comment: New to MySQL - so no.

Comment: Does it matter if 'station' facts come after 'opened' facts? If so, what's the criteria that determines the order of facts? BTW, you definitely do NOT need a user defined function for this!

Comment: Any order is fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Strawberry I even not good at mysql, but I know function in mysql so I suggested. Can you explanation your answer for me? can you add in answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT termid
     , GROUP_CONCAT(facts SEPARATOR '; ') facts
  FROM 
     ( SELECT f.termid
            , CONCAT(facttype,': ',GROUP_CONCAT(fact SEPARATOR ', ')) facts 
         FROM facts f 
        GROUP 
           BY termid
           , facttype
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY termid;
```